# Generate an installer

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

Over the years our InstallShield code has grown un-manageable and messy. We're about to design an InstallShield 2015 installation from scratch for a new major release, and I was wondering if there's any way to automatically capture a set of system changes to use as a cleaner starting point for developing a new install package. Ideally, I would like to turn on some capturing software, install the oldest release from which we support an upgrade, install the latest service packs, and then apply the manual changes that will get the new release running on the system. Then I would turn off the capturing software, and it would provide an InstallShield project pre-loaded with all the files and registry entries (GAC changes, .NET assemblies, etc) that were created as part of that install. Then I could add steps to delete those that we no longer needed and do some other clean-up and refinements. Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is called a repackager most often, in the enterprise world where sys admin and packagers prepare applications for deployment on the company machines.

Flexera has one that can create a project for InstallShield, but it is sold together with their [AdminStudio solution](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/enterprise/products/application-packaging/adminstudio/tab/features), which is not cheap.

We (at Caphyon) have a [repackager included in Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/repackager.html) (the architect edition) which also requires you purchase license. And of course the generated project will be compatible only with Advanced Installer, where you can configure your installers as you wish.

I think there is also a free repackager, [AppDeploy from Dell](http://www.itninja.com/community/dell-kace-appdeploy-repackager), but I never used it, so I don't know how accurate it is and if you can use the results created into InstallShield or if it generates directly an MSI.

If you started looking more careful you will probably find other repackager tools, but you should know that building such a tool is not an easy task so choose carefully. Also probably only the one from AdminStudio will be able to generate a project that can be read by InstallShield.

If you already have the source projects from the older editions I would personally not try using a repackager. Instead I would go for cleaning up all the configurations which you do not understand and re-build them from scratch.

A repackager as good as it can be still has some problems. It can capture incomplete data, for example if you have a custom action that runs different code based on the OS where the installer is running the repackager will capture only its effects on the OS where you run it. On another one might run differently and have another output.

Also if your installer has prerequisites and you run the repackager on a machine where those prerequisites are installed then the repackager will not capture anything related to this, so by accident you can forget to include required prerequisites in the new package.

There is also the things like meta-information which few repackagers can detect. For example files associations which are actually a set of file and registry entries connected together or environment variables, scheduled tasks, etc... 
Most repackagers capture all this data and simply show it to you as configuration files and registry entries, instead of creating the correct entities in your projects, i.e. files associations, environment variables or scheduled tasks in their correspondent views.

Comment: I guess a big part of my concern is cleaning up the things that previous installs have put there that I will have a hard time tracking down -- old Installer/un-installer Guids and other things added to the registry and file system outside the application's target directory. Maybe I should be asking about some clean-un-install applications?

Comment: Well, for this I don't think you will find something better than the MSI you used to install the application on those machines. Practically this is why Windows Installer was invented (in my opinion), because we needed a powerful system to manage all the connections you set up during an installation, which will be smart enough to know what to remove on uninstall, without breaking other software components.

Comment: I don't believe our old installers were in MSI format. That's why I'm looking to clean it up and have something help figure out everything the old installers did.

Comment: Ouch, that will most likely make you get your hands a little bit dirty. Maybe the solution from the following thread will help, but it is hard to say (I personally never tried something like this). http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?showtopic=21243